# Ansible adhoc command returning a duplicate parameter found error when using raw module

Tags: bash, ansible, ansible-ad-hoc

I couldn't seem to find an answer to this query here already and can't seem to find anything with googling.

I am trying to run an adhoc command on a remote box using ansible and I keep getting "a duplicate paramter was found in the argument string" failure, this happens when I use the raw module but not the shell module.

The exact error message is the following:

```
hostname1 | FAILED => a duplicate parameter was found in the argument string (variable)
hostname2 | FAILED => a duplicate parameter was found in the argument string (variable)
```

By example here is a command that doesn't work, it seems to object to setting the same variable twice, despite the fact this is valid bash:

```
ansible group -i hosts-file -m raw -k -s -a "variable=1 ; echo \$variable; variable=2; echo \$variable"
```

The reason I ask is because I am trying to run a command with a case statement to set a variable on remote boxes which do not have python installed and I am not allowed to configure them in any way.

By example:

```
ansible group -i hosts-file -m raw -k -s -a "
for file in \$(find . -name \"test*\") 
do
 case \$file in
  test1) variable=test1 ;;
  test2) variable=test2 ;;
  test3) variable=test3 ;;
 esac
 echo \$variable
done
"
```

The syntax here may not be spot on but hopefully you get the idea, it can't cope with setting the same variable multiple times. I know that in the above code I could get around the problem by putting the echo into the case statement but my code in reality is a lot more complicated than an echo so I end up with many more lines of code by duplicating the action into the case statement.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

EDIT: I am on ansible version 1.7, as per answer below, this issue does not affect anything beyond 2.0.

Comment: Please provide the exact error message you get as this works fine in my setup.

Comment: That was stupid of me, I have added the exact error message above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug. [Ansible is parsing the input string](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-1.9/lib/ansible/runner/__init__.py#L427) for args for some stupid reason. Try this as a work around:

```
ansible hosts -i hosts -m raw -a '/bin/bash -c "variable=1; echo \$variable; variable=2; echo \$variable;"' -vvv
```

This bug is also only present in <=1.9. 2.0 works.

Comment: That is a shame, turns out I am running an older version of ansible. The work around works a treat though, thanks very much for this